# Flutter Bottomsheet reload problem after dismissing keyboard

Tags: flutter, statelesswidget, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, texteditingcontroller

In a todoapp , am trying to edit a single task from a list of Tasks. After clicking on edit icon , I was able to open a bottomsheet widget using showmodalbottomsheet function with pre filled two text fields using texteditingcontrollers. When I tried to edit a single text field and dismissed the keyboard, the bottomsheet is loading again the previous value.I am unable to save my edited value..pls help

I used stateless bottomsheet widget.

Heres the Code. I know this not ideal way of coding. but am trying to get to work the functionality, later i will work on optimisation.

**Tasklist.dart**

IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
onPressed: (){
_startEditTask(context, index);//index is the single task from the lisview
},),

```
void _startEditTask(BuildContext ctx, int index){
    showModalBottomSheet(context: ctx, builder: (btx){
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){},
        child: EditTask(_taskList[index].taskName,_taskList[index].description,index,_editTask),
      );
    });
  }

void _editTask(String taskName, String description, int index){
    setState(() {
      _taskList[index].taskName = taskName;
      _taskList[index].description = description;
    });
  }
```

**EditTask.dart**

```
class EditTask extends StatelessWidget {
  EditTask(this.taskName,this.description,this.index,this.editTask);
  String taskName;
  String description;
  int index;
  final Function editTask;
  var taskNameController = TextEditingController();
  var taskDescriptionController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    taskNameController.text = taskName;
    taskDescriptionController.text = description;
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: taskNameController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Task Name'
          ),

        ),
        TextField(
          controller: taskDescriptionController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Description'
          ),
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text('Save Task'),
          onPressed: (){
            editTask(taskNameController.text,taskDescriptionController.text,index);
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: share code snippet

Comment: Hey, please edit your question to add your current code

Comment: Modify TextField's onChanged() method to update controller.text value to latest value received from callback

Comment: ty all for the replies..convering to Stateful widget solved the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StatelessWidget
```

to

```
StatefulWidget
```

will solve your issue  ---- try now

---

```
class EditTask extends StatelessWidget
```

to

```
class EditTask extends StatefulWidget
```

Comment: tyvm...I had to set the text to texteditingcontrollers in the initstate override method. previously I set the text to texteditingcontrollers in the build method..now after converting to stateful widget problem is solved.I don't know why framework is calling bottomsheet build method again when the keyboard is dismissed..

Comment: call twice ! (Navigator.of(context).pop();